# Does R count as an android dependency?

Tags: android, kotlin, clean-architecture

I want to build an app using Clean Architecture and I want to store the drawable id of an image in the presenter:

```
var heart = R.drawable.heart_red
```

My question now is can I use R in the presenter or does it count as an android dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's safe to use R in the presenter.

R contains a number of integers, it does not have any reference to context, so it's safe to store it in the presenter.

But the operation, like `imgeView.setDrawable(heart)` should be performed in the activity or fragment because imageView and any other view have a reference to the context.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an android expert but as far as I could figure out with google R is a class defined by android, correct?

In "Clean Architecture" Uncle Bob writes that the Dependency Rule is about code dependencies. So when u use the class R in ur presenter u would basically create a dependency from the presenter to R which lives in the frameworks layer.

As to my understanding this violates the Dependency Rule.

(But I am not 100% sure - I have a similar question here: [Dependency from Gateway to Framework in Clean Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589192/dependency-from-gateway-to-framework-in-clean-architecture))

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I think the first answer is right(But I am not an expert too).

Comment: I'd say it depends, you can argue that it is a dependency. In practice, android framework depends on R, but R does not depend on Android framework except for being generated. I mean that once it is created it is just a list of integers and using it does not introduce any dependency to your code.